# Entity Framework - El proveedor no devolvió una instancia de ProviderManifest

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

¿Alguien se ha topado con este error?

Según la documentación el error se produce por que no logra conectarse con la base de datos, pero revise la cadena de conexión y esta bién.

La comparto también.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Aqui sugieren reinstalar EF o hasta el visual studio https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551603/entityframework-error-the-provider-did-not-return-a-providermanifest-instance

Comment: como defines el dbcontext, usas Code First o es un edmx ?